# Get reports with campaign statistics by code

Tags: facebook-graph-api, statistics, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-ads-api

The problem is I don’t have an access to ads api so I can’t get information about campaigns like impressions or click through rate.

However, I can make reports in ads manager. I am fine with amount of data in these reports. The question is how can I automate process of getting reports in my application?

Is there any other way how I can get campaign information such as in reports with no ads api access?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this without Ads API access.